# Printing in Masm

Tags: assembly, masm

```
mov eax, val            ;ans=val+23
add  eax, 23
mov ans, eax

add  eax, num           ;res=ans+num
mov res, eax

add val,  20            ;val+=20

inc num;            ;num++

dtoa ansch, ans         ;print 
output ansis
output ansch
dtoa resch, eax
output resis
output resch
dtoa valch, val
output valis
output valch
output newline
```

I am writing a basic Assembly program using MASM, i need to do some simple calculation and print the results.

The above code is a snippet of a larger code, it works as intended,but i am wondering if it will be better to put the variables, val and ans, into registers like i did for res.

The examples i have looked at, put them into registers,is there any benefit in doing so?

Comment: Your program doesn't compile. e.g. there is no definition of val. Your question is about design in assembly language. Start with a description of your current design.

Comment: it not the entire code, just a small part i wanted to focus on. val and other variables are declared in the ommited parts, i did not think they will be useful to my question, i will post it if need be.